# Sink pop-up stopper lift rod comes loose too easily

Tags: sink

In my bathroom sink, the lift rod for the pop-up stopper is affixed to the "clevis strap" (aka "extension bar") by a "clevis screw".

Currently the rod is loose.  I know how to put it back and tighten the screw, but it comes loose every few weeks.

IMHO having a metal screw push on a narrow metal cylindrical rod is a design flaw.  Is there a way to mitigate the situation?  Maybe wrap the rod in duck tape or something where the screw presses against it?

Comment: Duct tape will do it if you can get the fitting on over it. You could also give the screw an extra half turn with pliers. That works for me.

Comment: It usually requires a tool of some sort to tighten the screw sufficiently. Even big strong plumbers will tighten it using pliers or some such. There are tens of millions of sink installs successfully using this "design flaw", and have been for many, many decades.

Answer (score 1):

*Ball rod assembly Sink Drain Repair Parts* ~$10. Or the whole tail piece kit for ~$60.

**Do not over tighten the setscrew.**

If it's really hard to pull you should replace the whole kit (the ball inside is messed up, or get a rod-parts-kit that comes with the lever arm with the plastic ball on it).

[image] [image]

https://www.lowes.com/pl/Pull-rod-assembly--Sink-parts-repair-Plumbing-parts-repair-Plumbing/4294857147?refinement=4294821109

Comment: You can use your old rod to match the finish. Really; just need a new 'set screw' part. - Didn't occur to me that you might not be using pliers.... "I know how to put it back and tighten the screw" *with a pair of pliers*. If it still comes loose then the part is shot. Larger bolt maybe. But that's not what I'd do if you were paying me to fix it.